# How to return different types in a method

Tags: java

I have this function:

```
private List<AssignmentInvoker<DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow, String>> getColumns(String campaignDTOenum) {
    if (campaignDTOenum.equals("PRINT")){                
            return List.of(DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths);
    }
    else return List.of(DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow::setPlannedUnits);
}
```

I need to move **DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths** to **PrintInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths** (different class)

Is it possible that a method has the change to return a different type?

I would need the method to be something like this:

```
private List<AssignmentInvoker<?, String>> getColumns(String campaignDTOenum) {
if (campaignDTOenum.equals("PRINT")){                
        return List.of(PrintInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths);
}
else return List.of(DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow::setPlannedUnits);
```

}

Comment: This is not a good way to write this code. Soon it will need to return _three types_, _four types_, etc. Just write one method per return type so you know what it does.

Comment: The real problem arises in replacing `DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow` with `?`.

Comment: It is not very clear why you want to do what you want to do Julian, but as long as the method returns what it is returning currently, it should not be an issue. It would be helpful if you elaborate the requirement.

Comment: You could have a common base for all the returned things, and then use that in the return type.

Comment: I agree that creating such a method is not the best idea. But if you want to solve your problem, use Object at your own risk or better you can create same Interface for your return objects.

Comment: If i use List<AssignmentInvoker<Object, String>> i get a compile error in the return lines saying: "The method of(PrintInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths) is undefined for the type List"

Comment: Why do you need this code?

Comment: What is the argument type and return type of `PrintInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths` and of `DigitalInsertionOrderTableRow::setNumberOfMonths`?